# Can't compile app built with earlier version of android on newer version of Android

Tags: android, mobile, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an existing Android app that was originally built using Android 11. However, the newest version of the ADT only allows me to compile with Android 17 so my app will not run. How do I get the newest version of ADT to run the existing app?

Comment: "the newest version of the ADT only allows me to compile with Android 17" -- it will allow you to compile with any Android SDK that you have downloaded. "so my app will not run" -- please explain what "will not run" means to you.

Comment: I get this error when I attempt to run my app.  "Unable to resolve target 'android-11'"

Comment: Along with the AVD remaining on the ANDROID boot up screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this error when I attempt to run my app. "Unable to resolve target 'android-11'"

Either:

- Download the API Level 11 SDK from the SDK Manager, or
- Update your project to use a build target that you have (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse)

> Along with the AVD remaining on the ANDROID boot up screen.

Either:

- Have patience and wait for the AVD boot to complete, or
- Buy a faster computer, or
- Switch to [the x86 emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)